# POST.getlist() processing

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm having problems with processing custom form data...

```
<input type="text" name="client[]" value="client1" />
<input type="text" name="address[]" value="address1" />
<input type="text" name="post[]" value="post1" />
...
<input type="text" name="client[]" value="clientn" />
<input type="text" name="address[]" value="addressn" />
<input type="text" name="post[]" value="postn" />
```

... (this repeats a couple of times...)

If I do

```
request.POST.getlist('client[]')
request.POST.getlist('address[]')
request.POST.getlist('post[]')
```

I get

```
{u'client:[client1,client2,clientn,...]}
{u'address:[address1,address2,addressn,...]}
{u'post:[post1,post2,postn,...]}
```

But I need something like this

```
{
    {0:{client1,address1,post1}}
    {1:{client2,address2,post2}}
    {2:{client3,address3,post3}}
    ...
}
```

So that I can save this data to the model. This is probably pretty basic but I'm having problems with it.

Thank you!

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the built-in form capabilities in Django?

Comment: Yes there is... the form is generated from XML data which is parsed from elsewhere. Actually I didn't even check if this would be doable with the built-in form...Would it be?

Comment: Not clear how you are generating this form from XML but Django is just Python. If it can be written in Python then in can be done with Django.

Comment: I know that Django is just python... I'll have to try it tomorrow to see if the django form is usable for this... I generate the form from the data parsed from XML... so I'd have to do this by supplying the XML data to "initial_data" in a form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, please drop the `[]` in the field names. That's a PHP-ism that has no place in Django.

Secondly, if you want related items grouped together, you'll need to change your form. You need to give each field a separate name:

```
<input type="text" name="client_1" value="client1" />
<input type="text" name="address_1" value="address1" />
<input type="text" name="post_1" value="post1" />
...
<input type="text" name="client_n" value="clientn" />
<input type="text" name="address_n" value="addressn" />
<input type="text" name="post_n" value="postn" />
```

Now request.POST will contain a separate entry for each field, and you can iterate through:

```
for i in range(1, n+1):
    client = request.POST['client_%s' % i]
    address = request.POST['address_%s' % i]
    post = request.POST['post_%s' % i]
    ... do something with these values ...
```

Now at this point, you probably want to look at [model formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets), which can generate exactly this set of forms and create the relevant objects from the POST.

Comment: Heh I knew there was a comment coming because of [] that was just because I was trying different approaches... Thank you. I'll try this.